# How to find latest Div ID counter

Tags: jquery, html

I've a bunch of divs with each div id starting with a common name and ending wiht a incremental number:

```
<div id="thisismydiv1"></div>
<div id="thisismydiv2"></div>
<div id="thisismydiv3"></div>
<div id="thisismydiv4"></div>
```

How do I find out the latest number i.e. 4 using jQuery?

Comment: Hmm, do you want the last div or the # 4 or the id of the last div?

Comment: Nice constructive comment @tereško, if you're going to bash it, explain don't be obtuse.

Comment: @Gabe , without additional information about the purpose of this mess, there i no way to tell, what for OP want this and what is the reason behind this question. ATM he is asking for `a patch of ( a bugfix for ( a modification of ( a solutions for ( a problem ))))` .. instead of explaining the problem and asking for the best solutions. It is a hack. A really bad hack

Comment: @tereško, How do you know it's a patch? You just contradicted yourself, first you say that you don't know what the OP wants, then all of sudden it's a hack and a mess. Please follow SO etiquette and don't insult people when commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var token = "thisismydiv";
var id = $('div[id^="' + token + '"]').last().id;
id = id.replace(token, '');
alert(id);
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/KTqwW/)

Comment: Use `.id` instead of `.attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last selector may help you - http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

```
$('div:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").last().attr('id');
```

or

```
$("div:last").attr('id');
```

[`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) or [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) will do it

Comment: he said he has a bunch of divs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[^=]` selector to find the elements where the id starts with that string, get the numeric part of the id, parse it, and check for the highest value:

```
var highest = 0;
$('[id^="thisismydiv"]').each(function(){
    var id = parseInt(this.id.substr(11));
    if (id > highest) highest = id;
});

alert(highest);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/cdQ9C/

Answer (score 0):

If the parent container only has these divs and your ids start at one and increment by one, you could just get the children count of the parent.

```
$("parent").children().length;
```

If not, you can use the `last` selector like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div[id^="thisismydiv"]').last().attr('id').match(/\d+/);
```

Will return 4.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rSSG8/